# Open multiple instance of a device driver

Tags: linux, driver

I already know that it's possible to open several instances of a same driver if this is correctly handled. I can do it now but part of the code is hard coded in the driver. So I would like to know how to pass arguments from my application (in user space) to the "open" function of my driver? (I know how to do it with ioctl, but I don't get how to do it with open)

For example, I would like to pass the number of the gpio on which a simple "gpio" driver is supposed to work.

Comment: Your full requirements are not clear. But it sounds like you can create device nodes where the minor number indicates the particular gpio to use. That is, opening `/dev/my_dev0` would request one gpio and `/dev/my_dev1` would request another gpio etc. Assuming your question is asking about a driver that handles multiple gpios. On the other hand, if the question is how to configure a driver to bind to a particular single gpio then that is a different question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, it is not clear. I mean binding to a particular gpio that I would choose when I open the driver.

I know that the code wouldn't look like that, but I mean :
gpio_to_pass = 2;
open(/dev/mydriver) and pass "gpio_to_pass"

then second_gpio_to pass= 10;
open(/dev/mydriver) and pass "second_gpio_to_pass"

Comment: Like I said, create multiple device nodes with the same major number but different minor numbers. Since the major number is the same the same driver open code will be called. The driver can then use the minor number to decide which gpio the user is requesting.